# Django: Ordering a manytomany field from the admin backend?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, mezzanine

I am trying to display a manytomany field by the way it's ordered from the admin backend.

Basically whichever foreign key is added first should be displayed first.

Currently I think django defaults to display them by ID, which is not what I want.

I had an idea of creating an intermediate relation with an additional date field for ordering. However, since we already have thousands of such object created, it would be very difficult to re-enter the data again.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: On widgets, there is no way to order it **on the admin**. If you don't mind having the same order everytime, every form, you can use a custom handler for the target class.

Comment: I believe the normal way to do this would be to set [ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#ordering) on the Meta class of an intermediate ("through") relation for some field. The admin should respect that also. It might not respect the _current_ ordering in the admin, but it would make the ordering everywhere the same.